# How can we implement a process between a Flutter app database (Hive) and back-end database (PostgreSQL) that can sync data automatically? (CDC)

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, database-replication, flutter-hive

We have a Flutter warehouse app that uses Hive to save data locally and offline. Now, I want to sync this data with my backend database (PostgreSQL) when the app is back online and connected to the Internet. How can I implement this process? What is the best practice for achieving this?

I expect to have to implement these processes with some techniques and maybe tool. I already know about the CDC (Change Data Capture) concept, but how can I implement it between these two types of database?

Answer (score -3):

To sync data between a local Hive database and a backend PostgreSQL database in a Flutter app, follow these steps:

1. Identify data changes in the local database.
2. Create APIs on the backend to receive data for synchronization.
3. Use an HTTP client like Dio in Flutter to send data to the backend API.
4. Implement logic to download remote changes from the backend.
5. Handle conflict resolution for simultaneous updates.
6. Ensure secure communication with HTTPS and authentication.
7. Consider using background sync to periodically check for internet connectivity and sync data when available.

As for implementing CDC between Hive and PostgreSQL, it's not a direct approach. Instead, focus on tracking changes in the local database and sending them to the backend for updates.

Comment: Really. chat GPT ???!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't want chat GPT, I asked here for some real experiences.

Comment: @rezate Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I do hate that the only answer you received here was one that appears to be AI/LLM-generated.  If you would be so kind as to Flag this answer for the Mods to be aware, that would be great.  As the person asking the question, you are in the best position to explain how and why ChatGPT didn't answer your question sufficiently.  Thanks!  And I do hope you'll stick around and give the real users here another chance ;-)